# Vitest [Function makeClient] is not a spy or a call to a spy! when trying to mock sightengine (module.exports is a function)

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, vitest

1. I was migrating from Jest to Vitest in a Next.js app
2. I had a mock on the package sightengine which contains a `module.exports = makeClient`  But when using vi.mock('sightengine', ()=>vi.fn()) I get the following error: `[Function makeClient] is not a spy or a call to a spy!`. The following test should pass as it does in jest:
   [https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitest-dev-vitest-ypyy3p?file=failing.test.ts&initialPath=**vitest**/](https://stackoverflow.com)
   Here system details of a minimal reproduction example (the one above)
   `System: OS: Linux 5.0 undefined CPU: (5) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz Memory: 0 Bytes / 0 Bytes Shell: 1.0 - /bin/jsh Binaries: Node: 18.18.0 - /usr/local/bin/node Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/local/bin/yarn npm: 10.2.3 - /usr/local/bin/npm pnpm: 8.15.3 - /usr/local/bin/pnpm npmPackages: @vitest/ui: latest => 1.3.1  vite: latest => 5.1.5  vitest: latest => 1.3.1`
3. The real code is more complex so using a spyOn is not an option and if I remember correctly it gave the same error
   **End goal:** Mock the package to use custom return values (`mockReturnValueOnce`)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.